# Reloading modules in JupyterLab doesn't work until I restart the server

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-lab, jupyter-kernel

I'm facing issues when making changes to a custom module and using it in a Jupyter session. The changes to my module do not take effect until I restart the server. Not the kernel. The server. Restarting the kernel does not work, for mysterious reasons.

I am aware that there are some caveats and non-intuitive things when changing modules and trying to import them in a Jupyter session. Normally, I would use the magic command

```py
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Or when necessary the explicit

```py
from importlib import reload
reload(module)
import module
```

Neither of these work. Restarting the kernel does not work. I keep getting:

```py
ile /gpfs/soma_fs/scratch/meulemeester/project_src/in_silico_framework/visualize/vtk.py:226, in write_vtk_skeleton_file()
    222     return diameter_string
    224 sections = lookup_table['sec_n'].unique()
--> 226 soma = lookup_table[lookup_table['sec_n'] == 0].groupby['sec_n'].mean().reset_index()
    227 lookup_table = pd.concat(soma, lookup_table[lookup_table['sec_n'] != 0])
    228 for dataname, data in point_scalar_data.items():

AssertionError: Length of point scalar data "Vm" does not match number of points. Scalar data: 13919. Amount of points: 13962
```

This assertion error used to be on line 226 before I changed it. Now it's on line 229. After restarting the kernel, this error persists.

I'm guessing (but this is just guessing, and I'm very uncertain) that my jupyter server is using some cached versions of these modules, and reloading them in the notebook does not actually do anything. Or the PATH has been adapted in a weird way, but then I would expect to get blatant import errors, and not this... I don't know what's happening here, and would very much appreciate some help!

If it is of any use, I launch my Jupyter server from a Python script as such:

```py
command = [
        'jupyter-lab',
        "--ip='*'",
        '--no-browser',
        '--port={}'.format(lab_port),
        "--NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'"
    ]
    log = open(os.path.join(management_dir, "jupyter.txt"), 'a')
    subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=log, stderr=log)
```

Comment: I don't think though this is general to all **modules** as your title implies. In the first sentence of your post you say it is a custom module. Make a simpler module and I suspect reload will work perhaps? (And then the title should be **changed to be more specific** as it is **not** modules in general.) Are you refreshing your browser when you restart the kernel? You seem to be doing some visualization stuff that will also relate to the fundamentals display things perhaps? You can need to restart more things to propagate the changes to the underlying infrastructure, too. That is why ...

Comment: <continued> for certain installs when done from inside running Jupyter via the magic install commands, such as ipywidgets that are complex and involve how things are displayed and rendered in the notebook, you cannot simply restart the kernel and get all the necessary changes propagated. (Indeed for ipywidgets installs done when Jupyter is running I often stress that it is best to shut down the browser and Jupyter and restart everything.) I'm thinking you have something like this perhaps?